# A pushdown automaton that recognizes the negation of a language

Tags: context-free-grammar, automaton, pushdown-automaton

As an example:

Say I want to design a PDA that recognizes the language of all strings over the alphabet {1,0} that are NOT palindromes. If I design a PDA that recognizes the language of all strings over the {1,0} that are palindromes and then swap all accept states for fail states and vice versa will I get the desired PDA?

EDIT: Is there a simple formal proof either way?

Comment: Note that the singular of automata is automaton.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The set of context-free languages (or PDAs) is not closed under complementation. (There's a simple demonstration in the answer to [What is the context free grammar for the complement of the double word over 0,1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5454153/what-is-the-context-free-grammar-for-the-complement-of-the-double-word-over-0-1), which constructs a CFG for the complement of `{ww|w∈{0,1}*}`. The fact that `{ww|w∈{0,1}*}` is not a CFL is well known.)

Inverting all the states of a state machine works fine for a finite-state automaton (and regular languages are closed under complement), but it won't work for a PDA precisely because of the stack.